# C++ code include error

Tags: c++, c++11

It isn't working, tell me where are the mistakes I made and why it's not working at all. I am sorry, I am new in C++.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio>
long gcd(long, long);

int main() {
    int m, n;
    cout << "enter the  1st integer =";
    cin>>m;
    out << "enter the  2nd integer =";
    cin>>n;
    cout << "gcd(" << m << " " << n << " )\n=";
    cout << gcd(m, n) << endl;
    getch();
}

long gcd(long m, long n) {
    while (n != 0) {
        long r = m % n;
        m = n;
        n = r;
    }
    return m;
}
```

Comment: Post the error in the question too, try spacing out code so it doesn't look like a book and title can piss off anybody haha.

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! You appear to be having difficulties asking good questions for StackOverflow. I recommend you read [the entire Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and head back when you have a specific, programming-related question.

Comment: Also encase you weren't aware this is not Java ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You included conio not conio.h you werent declaring std:: or using namespace std and one of your couts was just out. You may want to post the errors you get in the future and format your code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
long gcd(long,long);

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int m,n;
    cout<<"enter the  1st integer =";
    cin>>m;
    cout<<"enter the  2nd integer =";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"gcd("<<m<<" "<<n<<" )\n=";
    cout<<gcd(m,n)<<endl;
    getch();
}
long gcd(long m,long n){
    while(n!=0){
        long r=m%n;
        m=n;
        n=r;
    }
    return m;
}
```

Comment: thank u so much u helped me alot i am truly thankful

Comment: np, mark the answer as accepted if it worked.